# Will i be charged for creating a billing account?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-maps-api-2, billing

I want to use maps javascript API and to use the free trial $300.  However it says that I have to enable billing account and add my credit card information. So I just wanted to know that when i enter my card details will I get charged for verification like uber does.

Comment: There is no Google analytics map api can you be more clear as to what it is you are talking about.   THe google analytics api is free to use you do not need a billing account for it.

Comment: I just wanted to know that if I link my credit card with the google analytics account then will i get charged on verification?

Comment: Get charged for what?  The google analytics api is free.  How exactly is it that you are linking a credit card with a Google analytics account?

Comment: I want to use maps javascript API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial and to use the free trial $300 it says that i have to enable billing account and add my credit card information.So i just wanted to know that when i enter my card details will i get charged for verification like uber does.

Comment: Thats the Google maps api it has nothing to do with the Google Analytics api.

Comment: This is not related to programming. If you have questions about your billing account, you should file a support case instead. https://developers.google.com/maps/support/

Answer (score 0):

The Google maps api does require that you pay for using it [Usage and billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing) pricing does change from time to time. So its best to check that page.

In order to use the maps api you must enable a billing account using a credit card.  When you do that you are not charged assuming you have created a new account you do get the $300 free trial money that you can play with while you are testing.

So no you are not charged a fee for adding a credit card and enabling a billing account.  You will only be charged when the $300 you have runs out.